# tt_news LATEST view - if no news in category, show news from another category

Tags: typo3, tt-news

I am trying to meet the following requirement for a tt_news LATEST element and could use some help:

Example:

**There are three categories: A,B and C**

**Normally, display one item for each cat: A, B, C**

**If there are no News in A, display an item from the following categories: B (top item), B (second item), C**

So: Always display 3 items in LATEST.
Normally, one of each category.
BUT when a category has no displayable news, fill it with the next news item from another category

Is that something that can be done with Typoscript?
Or do I have to build my own userfunc?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with standard typoscript news properties. You will have to roll your own solution here.

Comment: Would you do that with a content object or with a userfunc and pure PHP?